# How to install wine on ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, wine

I'm struggling with installing WIne on fresh   Description: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

```
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.*.* 80]
:3 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic InRelease

E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/wine/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic               
Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is    
therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user      
configuration details.

sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 
wget -nc https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/Release.key
sudo apt-key add Release.key
sudo apt-add-repository https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-stable
```

I've been trying from official site https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu and also youtube videos, but both ends with the same error (above)

Any idea?

Comment: just to note, there is a ubuntu stack exchange that is dedicated, you might have more luck: https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/316025/how-to-install-and-configure-wine seems to be a good start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to install it by doing the following:

Add this line to `/etc/apt/sources.list` with a text editor:

```
deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ bionic main
```

Next:

```
apt-get update
```

Last:

```
apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-stable
```

That successfully installed the package(s). I didn't need to use `sudo` as I was running as root.